# How to send props to mousePressed function p5.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, processing, p5.js

My aim is sending props values to the mousePressed function so that it logs out the values of the mouse as well as clicked object.

```
let circles = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800);
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        circles.push([random(0, width), random(0, height)])
    };
};

function draw() {
    background(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        mousePressed(i)//This logs values even without mousePress
        fill('rgba(50,250,50,1)');
        ellipse(circles[i][0], circles[i][1], 5, 5);
    };
};

function mousePressed(i) {
    let mx = mouseX;
    let my = mouseY;

    //On click, log the values 
    console.log(circle[i][0], circle[i][1])
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: `mousePressed` is called by the engine whenever that event happens. you can't send parameters to it but only read them from the event object (MouseEvent). you then might want to compare distance of mouseX, mouseY from any of the circles

Comment: Check the [docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed). It's called with an optional `event` parameter. You shouldn't be calling `mousePressed`, as IT mentioned. In addition to a distance check, you could use `<div>` elements with listeners or test a pixel color value to determine what was clicked.

Comment: @ITgoldman not sure I understand you

Comment: you can check out about mouse position more on their [interactivity](https://p5js.org/learn/interactivity.html) examples. as for detecting **distance between 2 points** can see this collision detection [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74008667/3807365) which is pure js.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do adding the `mousePressed` call inside the loop where you're drawing the circles, but that's not quite how the `mousePressed` function works.

> The mousePressed() function is called once after every time a mouse button is pressed

It essentially has no context of the circles you've drawn, it just lets you know when the mouse has been pressed. Adding the function `mousePressed()` is you creating a handler, i.e this will be called every time the mouse is pressed.

What you want to do is know when the user has clicked one of your circles and output the the `x` and `y` of your circle. You can do this by using the [p5.js dist function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/dist). It allows you to calculate the distance between two points.

So your `mousePressed()` function might look like this:

```js
function mousePressed() {
    let mx = mouseX;
    let my = mouseY;
  
    for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      if (dist(mx, my, circles[i][0], circles[i][1]) < 15) {
        console.log(circles[i][0], circles[i][1])    
      }
    }
}
```

Where 15 represents the radius of the circle, I've updated the circles to use the [circle p5.js function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/circle): `circle(circles[i][0], circles[i][1], 30);` Where the 30 represents the diameter.

```js
let circles = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800);
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        circles.push([random(0, width), random(0, height)])
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        fill('rgba(50,250,50,1)');
        circle(circles[i][0], circles[i][1], 30);
    }
}

function mousePressed() {
    let mx = mouseX;
    let my = mouseY;
  
    for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      if (dist(mx, my, circles[i][0], circles[i][1]) < 15) {
        console.log(circles[i][0], circles[i][1])    
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```